# Nexus 5 camera brick/reboot bug

Tags: camera

I've had a nexus 5 for a while now, and one issue I've had is that after taking a bunch of photos, it will either freeze and need rebooting, or lightly soft brick wherein I need to plug it in in order to get it to turn on, no matter how much charge it had or has. No battery drain, but no key combination nor holding the power button for any amount of time turns it on, but it turns on fine when I plug it in for a moment. I have no clue when it started, and there is no specific number of photos, length between photos, or amount of time that the camera needs to be accessed that seems to cause it, but it only happens when I'm taking a photo or video, and after a couple or more have been taken. I've tried reflashing the entire phone, and it happens on both 4.4.x and 5.0.x. Is this a hardware issue or something else? Anyone with any ideas, no matter how far out, please tell them to me as I'm at my wits end right now. Thanks in advance for any info.

Comment: I see you did a firmware reflash but did you do a clean reinstall/factory restore of either OS?

Comment: @LivedWithOtters at this point a clean flash of the entire emmc really isn't that possible, however with multirom and a clean install of carbon rom I still have the problem.

Comment: Let's see if we can chase it down another way... Same problem with other camera apps (like snapseed or afterlight or whatever)?

Comment: anything that accesses the camera

Comment: Oh sure, take away the easy route ;-).  Let's work backwards from the symptoms... 1. when it freezes, is it in the camera app itself? what happens when it freezes like this and you don't do a reboot, but instead plug it in? 2. when it baby-bricks and you plug it back it, how does it behave? does the screen flash? does it vibrate? does it start up at the camera app? does it reboot from scratch?

Comment: When it freezes, the screen goes black and it acts like it's off, however the back starts to heat up after about 15 minutes by just a bit, and it can't be turned on. When it freezes holding the power button or anything does nothing, and the only way to bring it back sometimes is plugging it in. When I plug it in, it acts like it was off and goes to the black and white battery charging screen, with about the same amount of battery as before, nothing funny. I can just turn it on from there normally as though nothing happened. It didn't do that all the time, and most of the time now it only

Comment: turns off, though it will usually boot loop a couple times and require a force reboot, and doesn't just give up (loading screen displays until battery dies, phone gets kind of warm)

Comment: None of these times is it just the kind of crash where it just does a hot reboot

Comment: Is it possible something about what I'm doing is causing buffer overflows or something when it tries to write to emmc?

Comment: Hardware: Long shot, but do you have an alternate battery to try? Also, if it's not on already, can you turn the volume on for the camera shutter and see if it still makes shutter sounds after the screen goes black? In other words, I'm wondering if the OS is locking up or if the screen is. Software: thinking on it...

Comment: It's definitely the entire phone that locks up as the power button and volume keys do nothing, and none of the kernel gestures I have set up even vibrate the screen

Comment: Any chance it might be any governor or I/O or something? I've always set it to ROW for the I/O and elememtalx is the one I've been using for the governor recently.

Comment: Have you been using any of the dev tools to take a look as this happens? Even something like show CPU usage or process stats?

Comment: No I haven't. I'll try

Comment: Flashed a new radio and I'm testing it now...so far about thirty photos with no crashes